# 'Data Not Found' error when opening 'Yandere Simulator'?

Tags: technical-issues, yandere-simulator

Every time I try to open 'Yandere Simulator' Theres always an error. It always says:

> Data not found. There should be 'YanSimJune3rd_Data'Folder next to the executable.

I've tried redownloading and extract to different files but this didn't help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: are you running this game on steam or as a standalone?

Comment: As An StandAlone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably changed the name of the launcher. For example:

There will be 2 things after you extract it, the data folder, and yandere launcher, it has to be the same name:

`YandereSimulator.exe` and `YandereSimulator_Data`

Answer (score 0):

It was the same thing for me.
It was because I extracted the yangere simulator files with IZArc2Go. It makes it wrong and put a mess in the files. So I used another extractor (try version of WinZip) and now all is working perfectly... Good luck...

Comment: IZARC is malware.

Comment: To anyone reading this, please use 7-Zip instead. It's free software (I mean, really free), and overall better.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look for a folder named `YandereSimulator_Data` (it should be in your downloads folder) and move both the launcher and folder onto your desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I know it has happened to me. But all you have to do is move the YanSim data folder to the desktop.